# How to write Button.setOnClickListener in ViewPager

Tags: java, android, android-activity, appcompatactivity

I have three pages in one ViewPager and I create a button on the Page1.
When I click that button,I can go the other activity.

I want to use Button setOnClickListener in ViewPager.
My app can run,but that button is not working.

Here is ViewPager activity file.

```
public class ScheduleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private View view1, view2, view3;
private List<View> viewList;
private ViewPager viewPager;

private List<String> titleList;
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_schedule);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    PagerTitleStrip pagerTitleStrip = (PagerTitleStrip) findViewById(R.id.pager_title);

    pagerTitleStrip.setTextSize(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_PX,70);

    pagerTitleStrip.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);

    pagerTitleStrip.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);

    pagerTitleStrip.setGravity(17);

    pagerTitleStrip.getChildAt(0).setVisibility(View.GONE);
    pagerTitleStrip.getChildAt(2).setVisibility(View.GONE);

    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    view1 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_day__schedule, null);
    view2 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_week__schedule, null);
    view3 = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_missing__date, null);

    viewList = new ArrayList<View>();
    viewList.add(view1);
    viewList.add(view2);
    viewList.add(view3);

    titleList = new ArrayList<String>();
    titleList.add("Page1");
    titleList.add("Page2");
    titleList.add("Page3");

    PagerAdapter pagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter() {

        @Override
        public boolean isViewFromObject(View arg0, Object arg1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return arg0 == viewList.get((int) 
         Integer.parseInt(arg1.toString()));
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return viewList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public void destroyItem(ViewGroup container, int position,
                                Object object) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            container.removeView(viewList.get(position));
        }

        @Override
        public Object instantiateItem(ViewGroup container, int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            container.addView(viewList.get(position));

            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return titleList.get(position);
        }

    };

    viewPager.setAdapter(pagerAdapter);

}
```

And here is button onclicklistener file...

```
public class Day_Schedule extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_day__schedule);
    Button more_button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.more_button);
    more_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Day_Schedule.this, 
    MaintainActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
  }

 }
```

what can I do on these file? How to correct them?

Answer (score 0):

you have to set the button listener inside the view pager adapter view and class code 
try to organize your code to be more readable 
https://github.com/android10/Android-CleanArchitecture